# iOS - iPhone sound level low after recording sound using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

I have an app that I'm working on that one of its functions is to record a sound through the `iPhone microphone` and be able to play it back to me.

Problem: After I record lets say, me talking for example, the playback level is extremely low. Now I did switch from `AudioToolbox` to `AVFoundation` and this happened after the switch.  Do I need to code in a volume parameter for `AVFoundation`?  I'm not seeing anything in the `documentation`.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.  In the AppDelegate.m I have the following in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &setAudioError]; 

if (setAudioError) { NSLog(@"error setting audio: %@", setAudioError); } 

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride);
```

The important part here, is that it was not working because I initially had `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayer error:&setAudioError`

once I changed it to "PlayandRecord" I had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

When recording audio, or configuring a Record or PlayAndRecord Audio Session, the iPhone switches from using the speaker (on the bottom) to using the smaller earphone (nearer the front top), which produces a lower sound volume.

Your app can override this default by setting the Audio Session kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute property to kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker .  See Apple's Audio Session API documentation for details.

Comment: I've tried to use the above suggestion, and its not working for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on Airplane mode in Settings. Your sound will be much higher.