# iPhone 4, audio level issue after recording

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I am developing an iOs app that needs to record and play audio. I noticed on iPhone 4 that the audio level was much lower after recording.
This was fixed when I used the code i found here:[iOS - iPhone sound level low after recording sound using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101448/iphone-sound-level-low-after-recording-sound-using-avfoundation)

```
 if(!IS_IPHONE_5){
         UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
         AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
         AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
     }
```

This works great, but this causes the problem that if a user mute his phone, audio is still played (also other sounds in the app)

Is it somehow possible to detect if audio is muted? And if so, that we then not execute the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can check it this way

```
CFStringRef state = nil;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
OSStatus status = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);

if (status == kAudioSessionNoError)
{
    return (CFStringGetLength(state) == 0);   // YES = silent
}
return NO;
```

and modified method is

```
-(BOOL)silenced {
     #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // return NO in simulator. Code causes crashes for some reason.
     return NO;
     #endif

    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Only problem that i have now that if a user plays audio (radio or iTunes), and he opens the app, then the audio stops.

Comment: @WouterDeRuyck:- it's because that are system functions so the audio controllers are rolled over to them when they get started.